# Module parse failed : Unexpexted character '@' 1:0

Tags: css, angular, css-loader

[image]I am upgraded angular version from 15 to 16
Getting attached error after that

Comment: try removing `@charset "UTF-8"` it? [reference](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1253)

Comment: I dont have it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with some other libraries that you are using & have not been upgraded. Please refer my answer here: [Angular upgrade from 9 to 10 return errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78101111/angular-upgrade-from-9-to-10-return-errors/78102264#78102264)

Comment: Yeah but how to know what to update because i have updated most of the dependencies